# Other validation message is triggering instead of my message when using Ant design getFieldDecorator

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant design and this is my form when I click on save I am getting this type of validation msg instead of red bordered Antd validation msg

[image]

I want validation error like this which is shown in AntD documents. 
[https://codesandbox.io/s/do52z](https://odesandbox.io/s/do52z)

[image]

I have writter my function like this

```
      <Form  id="myForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Item label="Code">
                      <CustomInput
                        form={this.props.form}
                        type="text"
                        disabled={this.state.disableFields}
                        name="code"
                        id="code"
                        placeholder=""
                        required={true}
                        errorMsg={"Please input code!"}
                      />
        </Form.Item>
   </Form>
```

This is my custom Input

```
const CustomInput = ({
  form, id, name, placeholder, required, errorMsg, type, disabled,}: Props) => {
  return form.getFieldDecorator(id, {
    rules: [
      {
        required: required,
        message: errorMsg
      }
    ]
  })(
    <Input
      type={type}
      name={name}
      id={id}
      disabled={disabled}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={name === "code" ? "code-input" : "input-box"}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomInput;
```

and this is my save button

```
             <Button
                className="save-btn"
                htmlType="submit"
                form="myForm"
              >
                Save
              </Button>
```

I think I am missing something little here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant design input doesn't have required prop..
Required prop should be give inside form.item rules prop.

Since you have given reqired to input tag  it will cause Chrome to display a prompt that the user to fill out the field.

**Update based on comment**

Move formitem tag inside custominput component and try again.

```
  <Form  id="myForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                      <CustomInput
                        form={this.props.form}
                        type="text"
                        disabled={this.state.disableFields}
                        name="code"
                        id="code"
                        placeholder=""
                        required={true}
                        errorMsg={"Please input code!"}
                      />
   </Form>
```

..

```
const CustomInput = ({
  form, id, name, placeholder, required, errorMsg, type, disabled,}: Props) => {
  return(
   <Form.Item label="Code">
{form.getFieldDecorator(id, {
    rules: [
      {
        required: required,
        message: errorMsg
      }
    ]
  })(
    <Input
      type={type}
      name={name}
      id={id}
      disabled={disabled}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={name === "code" ? "code-input" : "input-box"}
    />
  )}

</Form.Item>
) 
};
```

Comment: I have removed required prop from, Now I am not getting chrome vallidation. But still I need to show Ant Design red bordered validation. why they aren't working

Comment: Updated my answer...look into it (If it works, select this as an useful answer, will be helpful for others)

Comment: Its working with the updated answer but moving <Form.Item/> inside <CustomInput /> isn't good thing I am using it at many places. Why its not working with <Form.Item/> outside